# How to format JSON Key values in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to format my JSON Document neatly in to an HTML page. My Javascript code is:

```
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          // Optionally, here you can update the dom to have a table in "responseDiv"
        //  var html = ''
          var text = xmlhttp.responseText;
          var newStr = text.substring(1, text .length-1);

          document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "<pre> <code>" + newStr + "</code> </pre>";

      }
  }
```

My HTML code is as below:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Digits</th>
     <th>Probability</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
  </div></div>
```

JSON Array:

```
{0: 0.99, 1: 0.8, 2: 0.6, 3: 0.4, 4: 0.2, 5: 0, 6: 0.12, 7: 0.09, 8: 0.001, 9: 0.0025}
```

I was able to remove the "{ }" from the JSON code but I want to display the Key Values in a neat format, which I am not sure how to. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please post the json or `text`  content

Comment: Sure, Updated my question with the JSON array.

Comment: which of the value do you wan to use ?

Comment: Are order of values important? If yes – you should use array of object instead of object with properties

Comment: Yeah, order is important. I want to display a table with heading as: Digits   Probability. And under those heading each digit and its probability should display row wise. It should display from 0 to 9.

Comment: That is not a JSON array... *sigh* That is an object with keys 0 - 9. Your array should be: `[0.99, 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0, 0.12, 0.09, 0.001, 0.0025]`.

Answer (score 2):

That's not the way to use JSON. You'll need to parse JSON into a variable and use it like an object.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(text);

alert(obj.YourKeyOfJSONArrayHere);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function, which allows formatting options. In your case you could use it like this:

```js
// Mock xmlhttp.responseText 
var xmlhttp = {responseText: '{"0":0.99,"1":0.8,"2":0.6,"3":0.4,"4":0.2,"5":0,"6":0.12,"7":0.09,"8":0.001,"9":0.0025}'};

// Your code
var text = xmlhttp.responseText;

var newStr = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(text), null, 4);
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "<pre> <code>" + newStr + "</code> </pre>";
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I am not getting any values back from server after trying this code.

Comment: Put `console.log(text)`. What does it output?

Comment: I did alert(text) and it displays: {
  "0": 0.99, 
  "1": 0.8, 
  "2": 0.6, 
  "3": 0.4, 
  "4": 0.2, 
  "5": 0, 
  "6": 0.12, 
  "7": 0.09, 
  "8": 0.001, 
  "9": 0.0025
}

Comment: So now try to alert `newStr`. If it doesn't come out then open developer tools and check errors in console.

Comment: It displays the same thing as that of text.                                                        {
    "0": 0.99,
    "1": 0.8,
    "2": 0.6,
    "3": 0.4,
    "4": 0.2,
    "5": 0,
    "6": 0.12,
    "7": 0.09,
    "8": 0.001,
    "9": 0.0025
}

Comment: No, I want to remove the double quotes for each digit and also the comma after each key value. Also, need more space between Key Value too.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: You can check the code below, which now creates a table row and two column elements for each key-value pair in the object, and assigns their `innerHTML` to key and value respectively. Then it appends the columns to the row, and the row to the `tbody` element that exists in your document. (Until a newly created element is appended to something that already exists in the document, you won't see it.)

--

Once you receive JSON data via AJAX, you should use `JSON.parse` on it, which will turn it into an object, so that you can run a `for...in` loop on it and access its keys and values.

So your code would look something like:

```
  //ajax call etc

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

      var obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

      //find the tbody element on the table element with class "table":
      var tbody = document.querySelector('table.table tbody'); 

      for(var objKey in obj){ // this will loop through all the keys in the object

           //create a table row element and two column elements:
           var row = document.createElement('tr'),
               td1 = document.createElement('td'),
               td2 = document.createElement('td');

           //assign object key to first column and value to second column:
           td1.innerHTML = objKey;
           td2.innerHTML = obj[objKey];

           //append the columns to the row, and the row to the tbody element:
           row.appendChild(td1).appendChild(td2);
           tbody.appendChild(row);          

      }
  }
```

Comment: How do I display both Key and Value respectively in each row using the loop method?

Comment: Cool, How do I make 0 and 0.99 (Key and Value) in one row? Now, in each row it displays Key on top and Value below.